# My Van is Slipping Gears

Tags: automatic-transmission, dodge, grand-caravan

Sometimes when in get into D in my 2005 Grand Caravan, my car will not go when I give it gas.  Or, sometimes once I have put my van in D, I'm driving and suddenly my van slips out of D to N. If I give it gas, it like I never put my gear in D mode.  What is happening with my van? Please help!

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid (or had it checked) to ensure it's at the proper level?